# Can I set the CSS border width for three borders with shorthand?

Tags: html, css

I have borders already set up with CSS for the .message class.

However I would like to make it so only the top border is visible with an inline style. Can someone tell me how I can do this.

Comment: try `style="border:0px;border-top:5px;"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use shorthand, you must set all of the widths, so you won't be able to use the width applied from the .message class.

```
.test { border-width: 1px 0 0 0 } /* top right bottom left */
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of that option (or, at the very least, I'd forgotten about it); +1! =)

Answer (score 4):

You can set all the borders up using the shorthand notation, but then override the one border you want to present differently, for example:

```
.message {
    border: 2px solid #f90;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Or, for brevity, you can simply override one property of that `border` (`color`, `width` or `style`):

```
.message {
    border: 2px solid #f90;
    border-top-width: 0; /* or whatever */
    border-top-style: none; /* or whatever */
    border-top-color: transparent; /* again, or whatever... */
}
```

Comment: All the borders are allready set up. I need to override the left, right and bottom. Is there any shorthand way to override or do I need to do each one?

Comment: You'd have to re-declare each one individually, or, simply, re-declare *all* borders, and simply reset the unchanged border back to whatever the default was; I can't think of an alternative approach, I'm afraid. Actually, I think [@cimmanon may have it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12512230/82548)...