# Is there a way I can set just three borders and colors with one CSS statement?

Tags: css

I currently have:

```
  border-top: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  border-left: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
```

Is there a way I can shorten this using one of the border shortcuts?

Comment: [You've asked something similar in the past](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512152/can-i-set-the-css-border-width-for-three-borders-with-shorthand), although the context appears to be slightly different despite the near-duplicate titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 2 rules is as short as you can get:

```
border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
border-right-width: 0;
```